# How do I hide a C# program at Windows startup, but not when opening the program normally?

Tags: c#, windows, startup, launch, system-tray

I have a (.NET) program that boots automatically when Windows starts up. However, I don't want the main GUI window to show (I would have it hidden away in the tray).

However, I want the window to of course show when the user opens the program in the normal way from the taskbar/quicklaunch.

What code can I use to solve this problem?

To add the registry key I use to load the program on Windows reboot, here is the code:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

rk.SetValue(softwareName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a command line argument in the Startup shortcut or the registry's Run key, like `/hidewindow`.

Then in `main(string[] args)` check if `args.Any(a => a == "/hidewindow")` and don't show your window.

Comment: I forgot to say, when Windows reboots, my program starts up from a key in the registry (to save certain complications).

Comment: I've just edited the question to give the code for the registry key entry if you could flesh out some code in your answer...

Comment: Instead of `Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()`, use `Application.ExecutablePath + " /hidewindow"`...

Comment: Works a treat, and your answer gets the tick due to the code - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you register the program in the auto run section, append a command line key, e.g. `/silent`.

In the program, handle this key to hide yourself.

Related reading: [How can I detect that my program was run from Task Scheduler, or my custom shortcut, or a service, or whatever](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/03/02/10503865.aspx).